# RxJS animationFrameScheduler stops working unexpectedly

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

**UPDATE** See below for workaround. I'm still seeking a proper solution or explanation to what's going on here.

---

I've got a problem this (custom) operator in RxJS (7.5.4). It just... stops working sometimes. What's going on? How can I fix this?
(Note, this also occurs if I use auditTime instead, so it seems to be something wrong with animationFrameScheduler)

```
import { animationFrameScheduler, Observable, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


export function debounceAnimated<T>(): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return (source$: Observable<T>) => source$.pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('A')),
    debounceTime(0, animationFrameScheduler),
    tap(() => console.log('B')),
  );
}
```

This operator works just fine most of the time. I see in my app that the action using this operator works correctly, and in the console I see a bunch of `A`'s followed by a bunch of `B`'s, as expected when the debounceTime fires.

The problem is that sometimes this operator just... breaks somehow.
I get a whole bunch of `A`'s when I perform the user action (in this case using the mouse scroll to zoom in and out of a chart), but the `B`'s stop completely and downstream observable subscriptions stop working too.
The application doesn't recover when this happens. Everything else seems to be fine, CPU usage is low, and other components that don't use this operator continue to work normally.

---

---

For a bit more context, this feature has been working fine for a few years, but a recent RxJS upgrade broke the previous implementation of this operator and so now I'm trying to find some alternative.
The previous implementation used this code, but it no longer debounces anything when written like this:
`debounce(() => EMPTY.pipe(observeOn(scheduler)))`

**UPDATE**

Alright, some more information, and a workaround.
I added this setInterval to manually flush the scheduler, and it works! If the bug occurs, then within 5 seconds this will completely flush the scheduler and things will start working correctly again. From scrolling in and out a bunch of times, it looks like a bunch of actions pile up in the animationFrameScheduler but nothing is handling them so they just lay dormant.

But why does this work? Why is this necessary? Sorry but this is where my understanding of the inner working of RxJS is limited.
Can someone please advise? This is a kind of ugly workaround. I'm going to shorten the delay to 100ms or something, but it's still not great.

```
import { animationFrameScheduler, Observable, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';


setInterval(() => {
  while (animationFrameScheduler.actions.length > 0) {
    animationFrameScheduler.flush();
  }
}, 5000);

export function debounceAnimated<T>(): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return (source$: Observable<T>) => source$.pipe(
    debounceTime(0, animationFrameScheduler)
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the full extent of the question. Could you give a few more examples on Stackblitz, perhaps with downstream observables to show what it is that's actually breaking? I did this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nhpuuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts and I can't get it to break! And just as an aside, are you unsubscribing from whatever observable is using your `debounceAnimated` operator function? Just spitballing but could that be an issue?

Comment: Thanks @deaks I've been trying without success to reproduce it in that stackblitz. I will keep trying, and add more code to get it closer to what I have in our environment. I might have to add D3 in there to replicate it, not sure. Thanks for adding that stackblitz! That's a great starting point <3

Comment: Not a problem! Feel free to post the Stackblitz here if and when you get something running. Before I added the `takeUntil(this.destroyed$)`, I had multiple subscriptions open after making changes to the code so I was getting loads more console print outs than expected. I've had similar issues before where there was way too many subscriptions running and it brought stuff to a halt. That may not be the issue but it could be somewhere to start looking.

Comment: In your actual environment, is the problematic stream responsible for rendering anything/calculating numbers to feed into D3?

Comment: @deaks Yes it is. Scrolling recalculates a bunch of data and then the subscription renders the new data in several places. Does that ring any alarm bells for you? The main symptom is that the D3 chart stops rendering. If I flush all pending actions in the AnimationFrameScheduler it all seems to work correctly after that. I've seen up to 14 AnimationFrameActions in its queue (probably more if I kept doing it for a while), and nothing ever flushes them unless I do it manually.

Comment: Without a more thorough recreation of the problem it's all guesswork at the moment. After the debouncing, are you subscribing to any inner streams/observables?